# Is there any js library for plotting function graphs in canonical (general) form? For example: x^2 + y^2 - 5 = 0; x^2 - y^2 + 2 = 0; etc

Tags: javascript, function, math, plot, graph

everyone!
Is there any js library for plotting function graphs in canonical (general) form?
For example: x^2 + y^2 - 5 = 0; x^2 - y^2 + 2 = 0; etc.
I know it can be easily done with matplotlib or with some npm packages, but I need to do it in browser directly (without any back-end code)

Comment: "*Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow*". You can probably ask this on **https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com** but please read their [help pages](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336) before posting

Comment: I've a demo app which can do it at https://www.singsurf.org/djep/GWTImplicitPlot.php. Unfortunatly the code is not open source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great library for plotting function graphs of any type: function-plot.js

https://mauriciopoppe.github.io/function-plot/

and with libraries such as nerdamer.js, math.js it becomes quite a powerful tool.

Comment: This library doesn't contain a single line of instruction for how to use it for someone who doesn't already know. It's full of complicated demos showing that it can do anything, and doesn't tell you how to do any of it. This question asks about doing it in the browser, but this library involves "tsx" files, whatever those are, JSON configuration files, and who knows what else, without a word of instruction for how to actually set any of it up, unless you want to use it in an "observable notebook", which it also doesn't explain what it is or how to use it.